# Cython tutorial failed at compilation [OSX]

Tags: compiler-errors, cython

I tried following cython's tutorial.

- https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-setuptools

After making hello.pyx/setup.py files, I execute it for compilation

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But what I got is like this.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:220:5: error: 'TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror,-Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_]
#if TARGET_OS_EMBEDDE

.
.
.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:181:5: error: 'TARGET_OS_E
MBEDDED' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror,-Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_]
#if TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED
    ^
.
.
.
194 warnings and 2 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Because the error/warning messages are very long.
I pasted some part of it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked me!

```
$ export CC=gcc
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
# success!
```

The enviromental value is the point.